# Java: plug-in not found: ErrorProne

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, errorprone

I have a java project, and I have the following setups for this project.

IDE: Intellij Ultimate 2020.03
JDK: Oracle 11.0.1
Maven: 3.6.3

Then, under Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Override compiler parameters per-module: Compilation optinos, I have

```
-parameters -XDcompilePolicy=byfile "-Xplugin:ErrorProne -Xep:ParameterName:OFF -Xep:FallThrough:OFF"
```

But when I click on build, I always got this error -

java: plug-in not found: ErrorProne

What should I configure for this project?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using JDK 11 set in PATH and 14 Idea's project configurations. I just changed project's used version to 11 (or maybe it should be set to what Idea is able to find) .

My config is pretty default.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
      <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
      <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-XDcompilePolicy=simple</arg>
        <arg>-Xplugin:ErrorProne
             -XepDisableWarningsInGeneratedCode
        </arg>
      </compilerArgs>
      <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
          <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
          <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.0</version>
        </path>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same version as [in the response by dhsrocha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66574983/10239573) and the only difference was in the version of the "maven-compiler-plugin", mine was "3.8.0".

When changed to newer version, everything started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij-->File-->Project Structure-->Choose your correct JDK home path for SDK

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue when running the test in IntelliJ.

I had maven version 3.8.6

under maven settings un-check the "Use settings from .mvn/maven.config" and this worked for me.

[image]